# Newbie Creating Game - Attempt at Clean Code - Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Trying to get better at programming. Working on building a silly game to teach myself, so its like an RPG type.

Inside the main:

```
String selection = "Warrior";
    if(selection == "Warrior")
    {
        Warrior war = new Warrior();
        characterCreation(player, war, 75, 200, "Black", 150, 90, 25);
    }
```

Just to create a generic character:

```
private static void characterCreation(User player, Character type, int armour, int health, String colour, int height, int weight,
            int damage) {
        type.setType(type);

System.out.println("New "+ type.getType() +" Created!");
```

So the idea is that you can create a warrior, healer, wizard you get the idea :)

Character.java

```
    private Character type;
    public Character getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(Character type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
```

Then empty Warrior.java class that extends the Character class.

The output im getting when it gets printed is New com.game.config.Warrior@6471d768 Created!

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your classes a viable `public String toString()` method that makes sense -- that returns a String that describes the current object and its state. That will fix your "com.game.config.Warrior@6471d768" problem since what you're seeing is the default String returned from Object's `toString()` method.

Comment: Excellent Thanks Hovercraft. Always wondered when I should override a toString method! Just learnt :)

Comment: @Bitzal: but please understand that in my view a decent toString() override is a useful debugging tool, but it shouldn't be used to create Strings used for the GUI display.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently not even remotely close to learning how to use swing/awt. I'll keep that in mind when I progress though.

Comment: @Bitzal You can use something like `return getClass().getSimpleName()` in toString() method in Character class. Thanks to it you wont have to override toString() method in subclasses like Warrior toString(){return "Warrior";}

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `selection == "Warrior"`

Use `selection.equals("Warrior")`

== is for comparing references not values of objects

Comment: Thanks Pshemo - Changed. Makes sense!